# Aggregate DIR type in <dirent.h> is "incomplete and cannot be defined"?

Tags: c++, linux, glibc

I am having a problem with compiling a piece of code that I wrote that uses calls found in dirent.h to interface with directories in Linux.

Here is the offending code: in "FoobarClass.

```
#include "FoobarClass.h"

#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 

... skipping over unrelated function definitions ...

else
{
    DIR stage_dir;
    stage_dir = opendir(STAGE_DIR);
    if(stage_dir == NULL)
    {
        perror("StageTar");
        result = false;
    }

...
} // end else
```

The error shown is

```
FoobarClass.cpp:218:25: error: aggregate ‘DIR stage_dir’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Any ideas of why this might be? When I exec the libc.so.6 that I'm using to compile, I get this.

```
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.24, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.2.0.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>
```

Comment: What happens with `#include <dirent.h> int main() { DIR stage_dir; }`? Compiles or same error?

Comment: @user4581301 I get the same error, yes.

Comment: maybe `DIR* stage_dir  = opendir(STAGE_DIR);`?

Comment: @Galik That also does not change the error that I'm seeing.

Comment: @zkabitz Well it works for me. :)

Comment: It's an improvement (probably the next error you'd find) but yeah. You should be able to instantiate `DIR`. I'm unable to duplicate. Open up dirent.h and see what's going on in there.

Comment: You should *only* use a *pointer* to `DIR`, not `DIR` itself.

Comment: @Galik I would assume that it would work for most! I bet that it is a problem with my build environment, but I figured I'd drop a line and see if anyone else has some intuition before I start rooting through the muck and the mud

Comment: @zkabitz Are you sure you recompiled it properly after making the change to a pointer?

Comment: You did change `DIR` to `DIR*` right?

Comment: I should mention if I replace DIR with __dirstream I get the same error but with "__dirstream stage_dir"

Comment: @Galik That is correct - I had verbatim what you wrote.

Comment: Including the `*` ?

Comment: You can probably use `std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator` with that version of `GCC`.

Comment: @Galik I went back into my code and made stage_dir a pointer type like you suggested and it worked! I must have been mistaken when I thought I had typed what you suggested yesterday. If you'd like to make that an answer to this question I will select it as correct. Thank you!